# trim newlines from common powershell commands

Tags: powershell

Powershell commands such as `ls` add way to many new lines. For examples

```
>ls


    Directory: C:\Users\JohnDoe


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----         1/9/2014  12:19 PM                .py
d-----        8/20/2013  12:43 PM                .android
d-----         5/9/2017   1:08 PM                .atom
d-----        3/17/2014   7:11 PM                .nps
d-----        5/20/2017   1:09 AM                .cis


>
```

Note above 2 blank new lines have been added after the output and the copious new lines before and after `Directory: ...`

I would like common powershell commands to remove these extraneous spaces.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62833168/remove-blank-lines-in-powershell-output-generally

Comment: To clarify sancho's comment: the linked question has an an [answer with a working solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62838107/45375).

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error. This is by design via the built-in PS formatters, all PS cmdlets are controlled by them and they are located here:

> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0

I would not advise change them, but you can see this discussions about the formatters.

> How to change default output Formatting of Powershell to use
>   Format-Table -autosize?
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36794056/how-to-change-default-output-formatting-of-powershell-to-use-format-table-autos

You can easily remove spaces in strings/files or even complete lines, empty or not using the native and .net methods in PowerShell and Windows, ***but you have to take control of that output vs leaving it to the default parser/host***. There are lots of examples and complete scripts all over the web to use / tweak for you own use.

Example:

```
# Change the layout of Get-ChildItem output using the default simple properties
ls D:\Temp | Select mode,LastWriteTime,Length,Name

# Results

Mode   LastWriteTime          Length  Name                                  
----   -------------          ------  ----                                  
d----- 2/6/2017 10:17:04 PM           Duplicates                            
d----- 7/20/2018 12:27:52 PM          EmptyFolder
```

Just do a search with your post title or:
'powershell remove blank lines form command output'
'powershell trim blank lines form command output'

> Powershell get-childitem output formatting
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21763692/powershell-get-childitem-output-formatting
>
> Using Format Commands to Change Output View
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/cookbooks/using-format-commands-to-change-output-view?view=powershell-6
>
> Remove empty lines from a file with PowerShell
>
> https://www.pixelchef.net/remove-empty-lines-file-powershell
>
> Remove blank lines in powershell output
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32252707/remove-blank-lines-in-powershell-output
>
> Remove Empty Lines From Powershell Output
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21524469/remove-empty-lines-from-powershell-output
>
> Delete all blank lines from a text file using PowerShell
>
> https://www.madwithpowershell.com/2013/08/delete-all-blank-lines-from-text-file.html
>
> PowerShell: Remove Blank Lines from Command Output
>
> https://www.mcbsys.com/blog/2011/03/powershell-remove-blank-lines-from-command-output